# Давайте жечь плагины!

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Есть метка [plugin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugin).
Она как мне кажется не упрощает поиск, категоризацию и по факту может относиться к чему угодно от [жуквери-плюгинов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b6%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2) до плагинов к джире.

У разработки плагинов, как [независимо компилируемых программных модулей, динамически подключаемых к основной программе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD) размуеется есть своя специфика, но эта метка занимается не ей. Фактически она обречена быть пристанищем желающих подключить "что-нибудь к чему-нибудь".

Я ставлю под сомнение необходимость этой метки. Предлагаю выкорчевать ее, потом сжечь, а прах развеять по свежему новогоднему ветру.

Answer (score 6):

Я предлагаю сжечь, но сначала разбить на специфические (к примеру, [jquery-plugins](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-plugins), [jira-plugins](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-plugins) и т.д.), если тема достаточно широка.

Я не считаю, что это хорошо, когда метка имеет разные цели и значения в зависимости от другиx меток и/или контекста.

Answer (score 0):

А я предлагаю оставить.

Метки можно использовать не только для положительного, но и для отрицательного поиска.

У написания плагинов есть своя специфика. У поиска плагинов (как и библиотек) - тоже.